# Animate cc (Canvas). Access variable created earlier in the same timeline

Tags: javascript, animate-cc

In a MovieClip on the main timeline I have on frame 2:

```
var count = 1;
console.log(count);
```

...and it returns 1. no problem. However I can't access it further down the timeline.

The following doesn't work:

```
console.log(count);
console.log(this.count);
console.log(parent.count);
```

Answer (score 0):

not using 'var' solves the problem.